# Docker : how to print jvm memory informations when running docker logs

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I ve a java spring-boot app based , running on Docker.

Within my **dockerfile** , i'm using **Entrypoint** .

Obviously , i ve used it like this :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dfile.encoding=utf-8", "-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError","-Xms256m","-Xmx256m", "-XshowSettings:vm","-jar","/opt/myapp.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=server"]
```

Like this , when the container starts : it displays this such values when running `docker logs`:

```
VM settings:
    Min. Heap Size: 256.00M
    Max. Heap Size: 256.00M
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)
```

But with a little transformation the the entrypoint format (to inject some en vars) :

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /opt/myapp.jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms=${XMS_VALUE} -Xmx=${XMX_VALUE} -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal --spring.profiles.active=server
```

That hides the jvm values , and displays only spring chart :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)
```

**How may i let it appear again ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `JVM` options and arguments is important. Usage is:

```
 java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

therefore the `JVM` options must be placed before the `-jar` option otherwise they are considered application arguments

```
ENTRYPOINT java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError \
    -Xms${XMS_VALUE} -Xmx${XMX_VALUE} \
    -XshowSettings:vm -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings:vm \
    -jar /opt/myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=server
```

Run it with:

```
docker run -e XMX_VALUE=256M -e XMS_VALUE=256m <image_name>
```

Comment: one more question , that catch me Invalid initial heap size: -Xms=256m ;; that tels you something ?

Comment: @firasKoubaa It should be -Xms256m. Remove the = in ENTRYPOINT